# Various AMD driver issues

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, amd-graphics

I've recently deleted windows to fully switch to Ubuntu, but I've hit a few snags along the way. First being, when I try and boot into Ubuntu and dont use the nomodeset addition to grub, it simply loads up a black screen I cant interact with. After that workaround, I still have other problems. The aspect ratio and resolution of my screen are wrong and cant be changed, likely caused by video driver problems similar to the first issue, the screen flashes black when I hit play on Youtube videos, and as far as I can tell, I dont actually have the amdgpu drivers that are supposed to come with Ubuntu. `lshw -c video` doesnt list any video driver, which I've only seen recorded with failed Nvidia driver installs, and any attempt to use the proprietary AMD drivers reports back that I'm missing the generic drivers it uses as its base. Any help is appreciated, since I've made nearly no progress the last 2 days. Using AMD 3200G for video output. Ubuntu 22.04 from directly off the Ubuntu website, haven't edited anything outside the nomodeset edit and a failed attempt to install AMD's proprietary .run file for 3200g's video driver
Reproduced on 20.04

Comment: What you describe after booting is entirely due to `nomodeset` and exactly what it is expect it to do. With that parameter NO graphics drivers are loaded. You need to be able to boot normally.

Comment: That explains some parts of this thankfully, but since I cant actually install the functional drivers I'm not sure what to do next. Everything I've seen says I shouldnt need to worry since Ubuntu bundles the correct drivers in anyway, but those are what seemingly cause the failed boot

Comment: You don't need the proprietary overlay. All AMD Graphics are supported by open-source drivers already included and selected during the OS installation, `radeon` for legacy hardware, `amdgpu`for everything else. Again, it *should* work out of the box. Which Ubuntu release/flavor? Haven't you by any chance installed in Legacy ("BIOS") mode in a computer newer than 2012? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Added the Ubuntu info, but I dont know what you mean about the legacy mode. If you mean the motherboard's firmware, I havent messed with that at all. If its an Ubuntu compatibility thing, unless it does that itself I havent touched it

Comment: Can you try Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? 22.04 is new and appears to still have many issues (as evidenced by the many, many questions on Ask Ubuntu regarding issues with things not working in the upgrade to 22.04)

Comment: Assuming I can get a download link, I'd be happy to try. Didnt see anywhere on the Ubuntu page, but I'll check again real quick

Comment: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/

Comment: It seems 20.04 has the same issue. I havent been able to boot into a live USB so far using the normal ubuntu settings. Safe mode will likely work, but I have to imagine it will have the same outcome as 22.04. I'll try safemode as soon as I can get the USB set up correctly again, as the failed boot states and my forced shutdown after appears to corrupt the live ubuntu instance

Answer (score 1):

Solved by disabling something called CSM in motherboard settings. Dont know why that worked or if its a permanent fix, but I tried it on a suggestion about black screen booting on someone's old dell machine.